# Using SKAction follow path on a node on an SKNode that moves doesn't work

Tags: ios7, ios8, sprite-kit

Sorry if that doesn't make sense, here's an example chunk of code:

**Scene.m**

```
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background.png"];
    center = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"center.png"];

    [self addChild:background];
    [background addChild:center];

    float xpos = 0;
    float ypos = 20*20;

    SKShapeNode *block = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRect:CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 20, 20)];
    block.fillColor = [SKColor blueColor];
    block.name = @"block";

    [background addChild:block];

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, xpos, ypos);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0, xpos + 100, ypos / 2, 0, 0);

    SKAction *followline = [SKAction followPath:path asOffset:YES orientToPath:YES duration:10];
    [block runAction:followline];
```

What happens is the path is offscreen on the bottom half where the rest of the background image is. Is this an anchor issue, a position issue? If I rotate the background node things get all messed up to but even in this simple case the path is not working as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a node that follows a path as a child of another node that moves. The reason the node in your app doesn't follow the path as expect is it's an `SKShapeNode`, which doesn't work well with `followPath` `SKAction`s. If you change the shape node to a `SKSpriteNode`, the node will follow the path as expected.